# CodeIgniter passing array info to $data variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im getting matches from a Model `Games_Model()` in DB table `match_schedule` the model works 100% no problem. I then pass the model method `getMatchInfo()` to the view and assign it to the `$data` variable `$data['games']` which is passed as a parameter in the `view` method as such

```
    $data['games'] = $this->games_model->getUpcomingGames();
    $this->load->view('templates/upcoming_fixtures_tbl', $data);
```

**Output**

When I do a `print_r($games)` in `templates/upcomg_fixtures.php` I get the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gameID] => 380
            [weekNum] => 1
            [gameTimeEastern] => 2018-06-14 18:00:00
            [homeID] => Russia
            [homeScore] => 
            [visitorID] => Saudi Arabia
            [visitorScore] => 
            [overtime] => 
            [tournament] => Fifa World Cup
            [sport] => soccer
            [location] => Luzhniki Stadium, Moscow
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gameID] => 123
            [weekNum] => 1
            [gameTimeEastern] => 2018-09-06 20:20:00
            [homeID] => Philadelph
            [homeScore] => 
            [visitorID] => Atlanta Falcons
            [visitorScore] => 
            [overtime] => 
            [tournament] => NFL
            [sport] => AM Football
            [location] => Lincoln Financial Field
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gameID] => 81
            [weekNum] => 14
            [gameTimeEastern] => 2018-05-18 00:00:00
            [homeID] => Hurricanes
            [homeScore] => 0
            [visitorID] => Reds
            [visitorScore] => 0
            [overtime] => 
            [tournament] => Super Rugby
            [sport] => rugby
            [location] => Westpac Stadium
        )

)
```

**Problem**

However as soon as I try to work with the `$games` variable I get an error

`foreach ($games as $game){
echo $game['gameID'];
}`

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

**Question**

*How can I access the games variable?*

**Relevant code Follows Below:**

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {
public function dashboard($page = 'dashboard')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/users/' . $page . '.php')){
            show_404();
        }
        //HERE DATA GETS PASSED AS ARRAY
        $data['games'] = $this->games_model->getUpcomingGames(); 

        $data['title'] ='WELCOME USER';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('users/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/upcoming_fixtures_tbl', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

**templates/upcomg_fixtures.php**

```
foreach ($games as $game)
{
    echo $game['gameID'];
}
```

**Result**

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

**Views**

[image]

*How can I access the array indexes in my views?*

In help, advice, constructive criticism appreciated.

Comment: It's an object bro. Do `$game->gameID` instead.

Comment: And that worked (banging head against wall) Sorry im new to codeIgniter. If you post as answer Ill accept

Comment: It's fine sir. I consider it just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you**

`$games` is an object array

do it like this in your view `templates/upcomg_fixtures.php`:

```
if (! empty($games)) 
{
    foreach ($games as $game)
    {
       echo $game->gameID;
       /* echo $game->weekNum; and so on */
    }
}
```

Comment: Pradeep is it fine to mix HTML & PHP like this in a MVC framework?

Comment: my pleasure , happy coding